# convert TIF works, Magick++ read same TIF, ABORTS

Tags: c++, imagemagick-convert, magick++

I can use from command line the convert command to transform some.tif to anything else.
But when I use the read command in Magick++ program, it failes to read the same TIF file, with following message:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::WarningCoder'
what(): convert1: some.tiff: unknown field with tag 33780 (0x83f4) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/768
**Aborted**"

I compile my C++ program with "c++ -o convert1 convert1.cpp `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`"

Can you please point out what am I doing wrong?

Thank you,